# Moving from Windows to Ubuntu. What programs to use instead of the usual one?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-10.04

I want to change my OS from Windows XP to Ubuntu 10.10 . But I like some programs in Windows, so is there a GOOD programs in Linux(Ubuntu) to change this list of programs? And I'll be appreciated for some links where I can download GOOD software for Linux. I need such programs, that I could open their files in Windows OS environment. For example: .doc, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .txt and others. Thanx!

Musical players:
Aimp
Winamp
Sound forge

Codecs for video, audio etc.

Microsoft Office 2003, Vizio, WinRAR,  Adobe reader, Dejavju reader, Fine Reader, Adobe Photoshop, Paint, Nero,   Alcohol 120%, DaemonTools, Far, Total Commander, Dreamweaver, Visual Studio  2005, Denwer

Messangers:
QiP, ICQ, Skype

Browsers:
Opera, Mozila

Antiviruses!!
NOD32, Avast, Kaspersky?

Translators:
Lingvo 12,
Pragma

BitTorrent, Download Master.

Comment: This question is much better suited to http://ubuntu.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Try posting this on http://askubuntu.com/. SO is for programming questions, so you won't get much help here.

Comment: Just search in the package manager, there are tons of good applications that you can search by keyword.

Comment: This is a very subjective question - best to look at an established online directory for this purpose - see Jeff's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Musical players: Aimp Winamp Sound forge
Totem or amarok for playback, audacity for simple editing...if you need more there's a lot of reading to do

Kodecks for video, audio etc.
ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons in synaptic

Microsoft Office 2003, Vizio, WinRAR, Adobe reader, Dejavju reader, Fine Reader, Adobe Photoshop, Paint, Nero, Alcohol 120%, DiamonTools, Far, Total Commander, Dreamveawer, Visual Studio 2005, Denwer

Openoffice does a lot vizio, rar extension for file-roller does rar, evince for pdf reading, dejavu i don't use so idk, gimp for photoshop/paint, you don't need a separate application for virtualdrive on nix....it's a command-line thing - k3b for burning isos, far/total commander idk, dreamweaver use netbeans or a zend for linux product(if you must have dreamweaver use it in VM), VS netbeans or eclipse, denwer - idk

Messangers: QiP, ICQ, Skype
Skype has a linux version, all other IM through empathy

Browsers: Opera, Mozila
both of these browsers are available on linux

Antiviruses!! NOD32, Avast, Kaspersky?
sorry but google this...many AV has linux versions

Translators: Lingvo 12, Pragma
idk

BitTorrent, Download Master.
transmission bit torrent client

Answer (score 3):

http://www.osalt.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/) is a good source of, well, alternatives to software.